# Why are BottomNavigationBar and TabBar blank in Flutter when the app runs for the 1st time?

Tags: flutter

The icons and texts on my `BottomNavigationBar` and `TabBar` are blank when the app is started, both in the simulator and on a real phone. When you touch any of the "hidden" tab icons or texts, they work well and all of them are shown immediately. Or if I change to another whole screen widget and come back, all of them will be shown, too. If I restart the app using "hot reload" in the simulator, all are shown too.

I'm not sure when this bug occurs because I almost didn't close my app in the simulator and uses "hot reload" to debug for several days.

Can't anyone help me please. I don't even know where to start to locate the problem. The original codes are too complex and I can't make this issue reappear in a new project with `BottomeNavigationBar` or `TabBar`. Please give me a direction that I can work in or provide more detailed information. Thanks!

=================update=======================

While testing, I noticed this warning, and found a related discussion here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72632

D/skia    (15157): WARNING: failed to attach a stencil buffer. Rendering will be skipped.

==============update==================

Problem is solved by upgrading Flutter to 1.26.0-2.0.pre.363 from 1.26.0-2.0.pre.179

Comment: Please add your code @ArtS.

Comment: Have you checked if your icons have the same color as the background?

Comment: @Zeus I understand the principles on stackoverflow. However I can't reproduce this issue with simple new project codes. And the original codes are too complex to put here. So if someone with similar experience or more debug experience than me could give me some guide on which direction I should look into, then I could provide more useful details.

Comment: @Cedric Thanks for your input. They have different colors. Otherwise they won't show if I "hot reload" the app or change tabs.

Comment: Sounds to me like you maybe have a condition for displaying them, and the widget doesn't rebuild at the appropriate time, initially. Is it a stateful widget? We would still need much more information about the logic inside it, whether you include code or not. Even a non-reproducible, but representative example of your widget code (without unnecessary bloat) would help us all help you.

Comment: @casraf Thank you. It is a stateful widget. I'll post some example codes later, after doing some more tests.

Comment: Problem is solved by upgrading Flutter to 1.26.0-2.0.pre.363 from 1.26.0-2.0.pre.179. Thank you all for help!