# Using TabBar or a PageView in Flutter shows a blank screen when starting/re-starting the application (Issue faced only on a real device)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Whenever I launch/re-launch my application on a real device the screen doesn't load or render the widgets until I make some touch inputs like scrolling the list (that is present in the home screen but not yet visible/rendered) or swiping between screens (the tabs under tabbar/pageview), without these manual touch inputs the app doesn't render these widgets automatically. It works fine on the emulator, the issue only exists on a real device for me. I found a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65721240/13509886) which might help understand the problem a bit better.

The main screen of the application fetches data from a local SQLite Database and displays it in a ListView, I use provider to fetch data and update the UI, and I use `FutureBuilder` to build the widgets.

I am aware that the TabBar doesn't persist state and I tried to fix it using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in all my Stateful Widgets under the TabBar as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61385007/13509886), but that too didn't work for me. Everything works fine for me when I'm just using a BottomNavBar or just without the TabBar or PageView.

I also tried to use PageController with BottomNavBar because I want that swipe to change tabs feature, but I'm facing the same issue again. Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../../widgets/custom_scaffold.dart';
import './all_tasks_list.dart';
import './todays_task_list.dart';
import './task_input_field.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  int _activePage = 0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<String> appBarTitles = [
    DateFormat('EEE, MMM d').format(DateTime.now()),
    'Summary'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyScaffold(
      appBarTitle: appBarTitles[_activePage],
      body: PageView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
            parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        controller: _pageController,
        children: const [
          TodaysTasks(),
          AllTasksList(),
        ],
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _activePage = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(size: 35),
        selectedFontSize: 0,
        currentIndex: _activePage,
        onTap: (index) {
          _pageController.animateToPage(
            index,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
            curve: Curves.ease,
          );
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.task),
            label: 'Today',
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.history),
            label: 'History',
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TodaysTasks extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodaysTasks({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TodaysTasks> createState() => _TodaysTasksState();
}

class _TodaysTasksState extends State<TodaysTasks>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Column(
      children: const [
        Flexible(child: TodaysTasksList()),
        TaskInputTextField(),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

all_tasks_list.dart:

```
// All Imports...

class AllTasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllTasksList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AllTasksList> createState() => _AllTasksListState();
}

class _AllTasksListState extends State<AllTasksList>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future:
          Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context, listen: false).fetchAndSetTasks(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          List<TaskModel> listOfTasks =
              Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context).getAllTasks;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listOfTasks.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              title: Text(listOfTasks[index].taskTitle),
              subtitle:
                  Text(DateMethods.dateFormatter(listOfTasks[index].timeStamp)),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

todays_task_list.dart:

```
// Imports...

class TodaysTasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodaysTasksList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TodaysTasksList> createState() => _TodaysTasksListState();
}

class _TodaysTasksListState extends State<TodaysTasksList>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchAndSetTodaysTasks(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          List<TaskModel> listOfTasks =
              Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context).getTasks;

          if (listOfTasks.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('No tasks added today'),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
                  parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
              itemCount: listOfTasks.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                key: ValueKey(listOfTasks[index].timeStamp.toIso8601String()),
                value: listOfTasks[index],
                child: const TaskItem(),
              ),
            );
          }
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class TaskItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const TaskItem({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TaskItem> createState() => _TaskItemState();
}

class _TaskItemState extends State<TaskItem>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final taskItem = Provider.of<TaskModel>(context, listen: false);
    return ListTile(
      title: Consumer<TaskModel>(
        builder: (context, value, _) => TaskTitle(taskItem: taskItem),
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        DateMethods.dateFormatter(taskItem.timeStamp),
      ),
      trailing: Consumer<TaskModel>(
          builder: (context, value, child) => TrailingIcon(taskItem: taskItem)),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class TaskTitle extends StatefulWidget {
  final TaskModel taskItem;
  const TaskTitle({Key? key, required this.taskItem}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TaskTitle> createState() => _TaskTitleState();
}

class _TaskTitleState extends State<TaskTitle>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    // returns const Widgets to be displayed
    }
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class TrailingIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  final TaskModel taskItem;
  const TrailingIcon({Key? key, required this.taskItem}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TrailingIcon> createState() => _TrailingIconState();
}

class _TrailingIconState extends State<TrailingIcon>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    // returns const Widgets to be displayed
    }
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  void deleteTask(BuildContext context, String taskId) {
    Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context, listen: false).deleteTask(taskId);
  }
}
```

task_input_field.dart:

```
// Imports...

class TaskInputTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const TaskInputTextField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TaskInputTextField> createState() => _TaskInputTextFieldState();
}

class _TaskInputTextFieldState extends State<TaskInputTextField>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  final TextEditingController _taskController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _taskController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        // TextField Decoration code
        ),
        //Just some usual TextField stuff
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  void addTask() {
    if (_taskController.text.isEmpty) {
      finishingUp();
      return;
    }
    TaskModel taskData =
        TaskModel(taskTitle: _taskController.text, timeStamp: DateTime.now());
    Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context, listen: false).addTask(taskData);
    finishingUp();
  }

  void finishingUp() {
    _taskController.clear();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered a similar problem. In my case, the PageView crashed only in release mode. I followed this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107133) and the issue seemed to go away.

In the thread there is a solution of delaying the runApp() function by a few milliseconds as shown.

Before trying this solution run `flutter doctor -v` and ensure that you are on the stable channel and everything is up to date.

Initial code.

```
void main() {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
runApp(
    MyMaterialApp(home:somePageView())
  );
}
```

Code after fix

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
  runApp(
    MyMaterialApp(home:somePageView())
    ),
  );
}
```

Please note that this is not the best solution but it fixes the problem for most cases.

Also making the main() function async has different views as shown in [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129121/good-or-bad-declaring-main-method-async-in-dart-flutter)